# Как обновить базу данных в VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle, ado.net

Есть функция, удаляющая выделенную пользователем строку из таблицы базы данных, а так же все строки из дочерней таблицы, содержащие тот же ID родительской таблицы. Но после перезапуска программы изменения не сохраняются, в чем может быть проблема?

```
private void buttonDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
int numRow = bindingSourse.Position;
string parentID = null;

DataRow selectRow = dataSetDP_DB.Tables[DataSpr.NameTable].Rows[numRow];
foreach (DataColumn prCol in dataSetDP_DB.Tables[DataSpr.NameTable].Columns) {
    if (prCol.Unique == true) {
        int numCol = prCol.Ordinal;
        parentID = selectRow[prCol.Ordinal].ToString();
        break;
    }
}

DataRow[] delrow = null;

foreach (DataRelation relation in dataSetDP_DB.Tables[DataSpr.NameTable].ChildRelations) {
    int k = 0;
    foreach (DataColumn chCol in relation.ChildColumns) {
        foreach (DataRow row in relation.ChildTable.Rows) {
            if (row[chCol.Ordinal].Equals(parentID)) {
                row.Delete();
            }

        }
    }
}
dataSetDP_DB.Tables[DataSpr.NameTable].Rows.RemoveAt(numRow);
tableAdapterManagerSPR.UpdateAll(dataSetDP_DB);
}
```

Comment: Нет commit (фиксации изменений). Либо вызывайте его явно, либо установите autocommit в свойствах объекта, отвечающего за соединение с БД.

Comment: Но у меня же нет прямых sql запросов. Если я правильно понимаю, для работы с транзакциями необходимы запросы?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что надо как-то вызвать метод, отвечающий за commit в ado.net. Фреймворка этого я не знаю, но в приведённом коде признаков commit нет. Если при закрытии приложения и повторном открытии строки снова на месте, значит при закрытии соединения неявно произошёл rollback.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваши пояснения. Но дело в том, что строка "tableAdapterManagerSPR.UpdateAll(dataSetDP_DB)" как раз таки должна вносить все изменения в базу.Но почему то этого не происходит, отсюда и вытекает мой первоначальный вопрос

Comment: Если запустить ваше приложение не из студии, а из папки bin, после удаления и открытия вновь программы удаленные данные по прежнему остаются?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете локальную базу данных, там есть один нюанс: нужно изменить в настройках базы свойство `Copy to output directory` на `Copy if newer` (ну или попробуйте другие варианты).